# Combine all the columns of two files using bash

Tags: linux, paste

I have two files

```
A B C D E F
B D F A C E
D E F A B C
```

and

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 4 6 1 3 5
4 5 6 1 2 3
```

I want to have something like this:

```
A1 B2 C3 D4 E5 F6
B2 D4 F6 A1 C3 E5
D4 E5 F6 A1 B2 C3
```

I mean, combine both files pasting the content of all columns.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `bash` solution:

```
paste -d' ' file1 file2 \
| while read -a fields ; do
      (( width=${#fields[@]}/2 ))
      for ((i=0; i<width; ++i)) ; do
          printf '%s%s ' "${fields[i]}" "${fields[ i + width ]}"
      done
      printf '\n'
done
```

- `paste` outputs the files side by side.
- `read -a` reads the columns into an array.
- in the `for` loop, we iterate over the array and print the corresponding values.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, trying to do some fun with combinations of `xargs` + `paste` here.

```
xargs -n6 < <(paste -d'\0' <(xargs -n1 < Input_file1) <(xargs -n1 < Input_file2))
```

Comment: Could you explain me what does it means the -n6 and so on? Because in my real data I have thousands of columns so I should check if I have to change the numbers in the command

Comment: @aguillenea, this means divide the lines into 6 column long lines. I am in cab so can't add complete explanation in my code you could ask me question here though lemme know in case of any further queries.